# Is there a way to set a minimum number of characters in a number input in HTML?

Tags: html, input, tags

I'm writing a HTML form that submits through PHP and I'm wondering if there is a way to set a minimum number of characters in a number input?

For instance, for an Irish mobile phone number it needs to be exactly 10 digits. Is there a way to set this?

Comment: Do you want to check number server side?

Comment: I want it to show an error such as 'you must enter 10 digits' to force the user to change their input.

Comment: Well... you can do it with javascript. Not sure about custom error messages for html5 validation....

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML  pattern Attribute with a regexp

```
<input type="text" name="phone number" 
pattern="[A-Za-z]{10}" title="ten letter country code">
```

for regexp only numbres use this :

```
[0-9]{10}
```

Comment: That specifies that I enter a value between 1 and 10. I want to force the user to enter 10 characters, as in 0872563345 not 10.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions . It forces the user to enter 10 numbers between 0-9

Exact 10 letter /^[0-9]{10}/

```
   <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{10} "/>
```